# NLP library for determining if a sentence is equivalent to another sentence?

Tags: php, javascript, python, nlp

I would like to find an NLP library in Python, PHP or even JavaScript for determining whether a sentence in a string is equivalent to a differently structured sentence?

For example, the library would need to be able to determine whether these two sentences are equivalent:

"Would you like the order for here or to go?"
"Do you want the order for here or to go?"

Is there such a thing?  Or would it actually be easier for me to build something like this myself for the specific application I need it for?

Comment: Check out the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://nltk.org/).

Comment: @Joel Cornett I've briefly skimmed over NLTK's feature in the past but will look at it more in depth again.  Their "classify" package that applies category labels to words might be useful in this case.

Comment: @Dominique: although classification might be a part of this task, it will certainly not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing is the task of "paraphrase" (or bidirectional "textual entailment").  This is an extremely hard problem and an open research area.  I doubt that there is a system available that would do well enough on this task for real-world, general use.

If you have a very narrow set of transformations in mind (such as the "would you like" <-> "do you want" alternation), you could try and construct a set of transformation rules that convert one sentence to the other.  These rules could act directly on the sentence or on a parse tree produced from a statistical parser.

Comment: In my case, I could use transformations because the variety of different paraphrases that I would have to process could be limited to a small number.  Your answer was the best because you named what I was trying to describe, which makes it easier to Google for more info. :)

Answer (score 3):

Solving this in the general case is most likely [AI complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete) -- just getting the correct syntactic analysis for a single sentence is a very difficult problem.  But if there's a limited set of sentence forms you're considering, then it's possible that within that limited domain it will be easier.